# Angularjs Navigation routeProvider and phonegap on windows phone 8 Not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-build, mobile-angular-ui

We have developed a simple test app on using angular js and mobile-ui-angular.
You can find the source here:

https://github.com/lnesitwo/html_5_template

So far the app works correctly on IOS, BB and AOS however on windows phone 8, the navigation does not work.

We are using phonehap serve functionality to send the app to the phonegap developer app installed on the phone.

The strange part is. 
On the app load the url that get called is: 
x-wampp0:/wwww/content_sync/downloads/phonegapdevapp/wwww/index.html
With this url the mainController gets to run but the template does not get loaded.

However if you refresh the app once is started for the fisrt time the app loads with this URL
x-wampp0:/wwww/content_sync/downloads/phonegapdevapp/wwww/index.html#/home
And the home template loads correctly but the navigation does not work.

And in addition if you reload the app but inside one of the pages the app load on
x-wampp0:/wwww/content_sync/downloads/phonegapdevapp/wwww/index.html#/page1
And the page template loads correctly and the navigation between pages 1 and 2 works but not back to home when you click on the app name in the main menu.

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-left"> 
  <div class="scrollable">
    <h1 class="scrollable-header app-name"><a class="main_title_sidebar" ng-href="#/home">Two Mobile App</a></h1>  
    <div class="scrollable-content">
      <div class="list-group" ui-turn-off='uiSidebarLeft'>
        <a class="list-group-item" ng-href="#/page1">Page 1<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a> 
        <a class="list-group-item" ng-href="#/page2">Page 2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Has you can see the ng-href is being use for navigation and is a simple 3 page template base application.

I have investigated and tried this solutions with no results in any of them:

-1

```
appModule.config(function ($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);
})
```

-2 the ng-csp and meta:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

-3 found angular windows fix js on other post inside stackoverflow.
and no results. https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat